# A TV Movie where a guy turns into a cyborg?

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I've been looking for this one for years now. I saw it as a kid in the eighties. I thought it was on NBC and seem to think it was around the same time as *Misfits of Science* but it was a one-time TV movie. I have found nothing about it though. The story I remember in bits and pieces but here it goes.

There are two scientist, one man and one woman. I don't remember if they are ex-boyfriend and girlfriend or if she is part of his lab for some reason. She is working on making a robot and he is working on teleportation. I believe everyone thinks he's just a failure and a crackpot though. The robot she is building is on the teleportation pad and he uses the other one and teleports to where the robot is. He's really excited and she is upset because her robot is gone. It turns out that he somehow combined with the robot and he starts to become a cyborg. The more he uses his powers the more machine he turns into and his robot parts glow blue.

Here are other scenes I half remember. He is jogging and his legs glow blue and then he has robot legs. Towards the end he is swimming in the ocean and he kicks off his shoes but the metal in his body is dragging him down.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It was an episode of [CBS Summer Playhouse](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0346222/) titled [Infiltrator](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0163007/).

CBS Summer Playhouse was a series that aired television pilots that didn't make the cut.  I always wished this one had.

Note: I think you got some of the details wrong.  I believe she was his ex-girlfriend, but she's also the director (or co-director) of the research complex where he works.  He's about to lose his funding, because he faked a demonstration using twins.  But now he's actually got it working, and nobody believes him because of the previous fake demo.  So he teleports himself into her office, trying to convince her that it really works now.  (I don't think there was a pad in her office; it was like a Star Trek transporter, where you only need 1 pad.)  The robot she's working on is a space probe designed to adapt to hostile environments.  It was programmed for self-preservation, so whenever he finds himself in trouble, it starts adapting to the situation (essentially beyond his control).

Comment: Wow and I even thought that Scott Bakula was in it but I didn't see it on his IMDB profile when I looked before. I now have to try to track down a way to watch this show.

Comment: @KevinHowell, if you do, please let me know.  I'd like to see it again too.

Comment: It's funny to because I also liked I-man and kept thinking that I was just inserting Scott Bakula because it seemed so much like I-Man to me. If I find it I'll let you know.

Comment: Ask and ye shall receive - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYEcL8ccGTc&feature=related.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens, yep, that's it.  Too bad the recording is such lousy quality.